# Capture my screen via a website

Tags: web, screen, record

**I was wondering if it's possible to capture a screenshot and/or record my computer screen(s) via a website?**

If it is possible, what languages would I need to learn/code? I already have intermediate knowledge of HTML, CSS, JavaScript, jQuery, and PHP.

**In other words: *I want to have the ability to capture/record my screen (not the website) via using a website (not an application).***

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Web sites are very deliberately given only restricted access to your computer for security reasons. Imagine the havoc that could result if a malicious web site were able to see and capture what was on your screen--banking information, your confidential e-mails, etc. Even if the user had to give permission for this level of access, it would still be way too easy to trick a user into giving that permission.

Comment: Thanks for replying! What if I was to develop a 1 click download browser plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could find/think of was http://www.screencast-o-matic.com/screen_recorder, but even then you have to download a launch plugin. I agree with @DLH. This is for your protection.

My favorite screen recorder is ScreenPresso - it is always running in background, and repurposed the PrtScn button as its launch key.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I'll check screencast out!